# Customtkinter: Change text color of switch

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter, tkinter-text

I want to change the text color of the switch widget text in customtkinter

I tried to use `configure` in with `text_color` but it showed me that there's no attribute of a switch called `text_color`...

Btw.. when creating the switch text_color works

minimal reproducible example:

```
import customtkinter as ctk  
root = ctk.CTk()
switch = ctk.CTkSwitch(master=root, text='This is a switch', text_color='yellow')
switch.pack()
switch.configure(text_color='red')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] and the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customtkinter is installed out of the box only with the .configure settings:

```
def configure(self, require_redraw=False, **kwargs):
        """ basic configure with bg_color, width, height support, calls configure of tkinter.Frame, updates in the end """
```

that you can see in the `ctk_base_class.py` file which crashes during an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ф\PycharmProjects\tkinter\rrr.py", line 5, in <module>
    switch.configure(text_color='red')
  File "C:\Users\ф\PycharmProjects\tkinter\venv\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_switch.py", line 339, in configure
    super().configure(require_redraw=require_redraw, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ф\PycharmProjects\tkinter\venv\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\core_widget_classes\ctk_base_class.py", line 137, in configure
    check_kwargs_empty(kwargs, raise_error=True)
  File "C:\Users\ф\PycharmProjects\tkinter\venv\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\utility\utility_functions.py", line 18, in check_kwargs_empty
    raise ValueError(f"{list(kwargs_dict.keys())} are not supported arguments. Look at the documentation for supported arguments.")
ValueError: ['text_color'] are not supported arguments. Look at the documentation for supported arguments.
```

This is probably due to the constant development of the library at the present time. To add the functionality you need, you can copy the lines you need to [github](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/b60859dfd6ca2301afd0494a8f561ae4bb021252/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_switch.py) and add them to a file on your computer.

```
if "text_color" in kwargs:
            self._text_color = self._check_color_type(kwargs.pop("text_color"))
            require_redraw = True
```

Then the method in the ctk_base_class.py file will look like this:

```
    def configure(self, require_redraw=False, **kwargs):
        """ basic configure with bg_color, width, height support, calls configure of tkinter.Frame, updates in the end """

        if "width" in kwargs:
            self._set_dimensions(width=kwargs.pop("width"))

        if "height" in kwargs:
            self._set_dimensions(height=kwargs.pop("height"))

        if "bg_color" in kwargs:
            new_bg_color = self._check_color_type(kwargs.pop("bg_color"), transparency=True)
            if new_bg_color == "transparent":
                self._bg_color = self._detect_color_of_master()
            else:
                self._bg_color = self._check_color_type(new_bg_color)
            require_redraw = True

        if "text_color" in kwargs:
            self._text_color = self._check_color_type(kwargs.pop("text_color"))
            require_redraw = True

        super().configure(**pop_from_dict_by_set(kwargs, self._valid_tk_frame_attributes))  # configure tkinter.Frame

        # if there are still items in the kwargs dict, raise ValueError
        check_kwargs_empty(kwargs, raise_error=True)

        if require_redraw:
            self._draw()
```

Comment: From design point of view, it is not a good design to configure *"text_color"* inside `ctk_base_class.py` because `CTkBaseClass` inherits from `tkinter.Frame` and there is no text color for a frame.  Actually `CTkSwitch` class (in github) has been updated to address this issue.

Comment: @acw1668 I agree with you. I leave the answer as an option - "look inside" when something does not work.

Comment: Its fixed now with version 5.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring CTkSwitch.configure(text_color=...) works in CustomTkinter 5.1.3.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the label attribute of ctkswitch object and call the 'config' method which has a 'fg' parameter. This changes the foreground text colour of the label which should work.

Replace:

```
switch.configure(text_color='red')
```

With:

```
switch.label.config(fg='red')
```

Comment: On Windows 10 it throws an error `AttributeError: 'CTkSwitch' object has no attribute 'label'`